# --- Crash data --- Flash plugin-а, в Chrumium под ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromium, flash-player

Не воспроизводится флеш контент, решил разобраться с проблемой, вроде проблема флеш плеера не сложная(думал я в то время). Затем после долгого копания форумов и сайтов я перепробовал слудующие варианты: 
1. Переустановить flash-player, скачав его из репозитория, до этого удаляя ранее стоявший flash-player;
2. Переустановить flash-player, скачав его из официального сайта, так же удалив ранее установленную версию; 
3. Установить flash-**plugin** отдельно для Chromium, с условием наличия при этом установленного flash-**player**;
4. Установить flash-player с официального сайта и поверх него установить flash-player с репозитория, при условии наличия flash-**plugin** для Chromium 

Как видите я пытался самостоятельно исправить данную проблему, но увы не получилось. Теперь я прошу вас, людей с опытом превосходящий мой в десятки раз, помочь справиться с этим
[image: --- Crash data ---]

Comment: Скажу честно, на себе не испытывал, мне флеш не нужен, но попробуйте эту инструкцию: https://websiteforstudents.com/install-adobe-flash-player-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-beta-desktop/

Comment: Забудьте об этой технологии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла инструкция с этого сайта https://websiteforstudents.com/install-adobe-flash-player-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-beta-desktop/ , спасибо **Beast Winterwolf**